# How to TDD a 2-steps process which requires input from a remote party?

Tags: tdd

I have a process which is composed by 2 steps:

- (step1) first it request a token from a remote party;
- (step2) second it uses the token to trigger a remote job.

TDDing (1) is pretty easy, but how to I TDD (step2)? If I write the tests as different functions I don't know where to store the token between the two tests (the DB is cleaned just before each test). If I use a fixture, (step2) will always fail because the remote job will not accept my token.

My solution up to now is to have:

- test1() which (of course) tests (step1);
- test2() which has the whole code of test1() plus the code for testing (step2).

While the solution work I don't like it, so I'm searching for something better.

Comment: "because the remote job will not accept my token" --- so mock it?

Comment: I'd like to test the process as real as possible... I could just mock everything up, but I was wondering if there is any "best practice" approach to this kind of problems.

Comment: what kind of tests are you writing? Unit? Functional? Integrational? Acceptance?

Comment: unit tests mainly, but I plan to use them for integration as well

Answer (score 1):

You say that you have a process which comprises of two steps. As you have identified these discrete steps you should encapsulate them into separate methods e.g.

(Note: the following code is *extremely simplistic*. It would help if you included code in your question)

Instead of:

```
void TriggerRemoteJob()
{
  // Step 1 - Code to request a token from a remote party.

  // Step 2 - Code to use the token to trigger a remote job.
}
```

You could have:

```
Token GetToken(string remotePartyId)
{
 return RemoteParty.GetToken(remotePartyId); 
}

int TriggerRemoteJob(Token token)
{
 return RemoteJobManager.TriggerJob(token);
}
```

"RemoteParty" and "RemoteJobManager" are both dependencies which could be injected into your class using dependency injection.

Taking this approach you could then use TDD to develop "GetToken" and "TriggerJob". When using TDD you should mock external dependencies and only test the method which you are developing. So when testing "TriggerRemoteJob" you would ***mock*** the token.

In your comment you say:

"I'd like to test the process as real as possible."

I recommend that you use a BDD approach to development (seach for BDD on StackOverflow, there are lots of great answers on this topic). This approach forces you to develop "outside-in inside-out", where you revert to using TDD as part of the BDD process. This approach will exercise all layers in your solution so you will test the process "as real as possible" whilst also writing tests (via TDD) which use mocks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are going `to TDD a 2-steps process which requires input from a remote party` so you definitely have to mock that `remote party`.

I suggest you use either [MOQ](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) or [NSubstitute](http://nsubstitute.github.io/) as mocking framework.

As I see **there is no need to write two tests because two invocations are so dependent.**

I'd rather write only one test to test your 2-steps process

```
[TestClass]
public class ClientTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This test can test only the fact of invocation only.
    /// </summary>
    [TestMethod]
    public void DoSmth_RequestsTokenFromRemoteParty()
    {
        // act
        target.DoSmth();
        // assert
        remotePartyMock.Verify(it => it.RequestTtoken());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// It is enough to have this test only.
    /// It contains token setup and following verification of triggering job with correct tocken.
    /// </summary>
    [TestMethod]
    public void DoSmth_RequestsTokenAndTriggersRemoteJob()
    {
        // arrange
        var expectedTocken = Guid.NewGuid();
        remotePartyMock.Setup(it => it.RequestTtoken()).Returns(expectedTocken);
        // act
        target.DoSmth();
        // assert
        remotePartyMock.Verify(it => it.TriggerRemoteJob(expectedTocken));
    }

    private Mock<IRemoteParty> remotePartyMock;
    private Client target;

    public void Init()
    {
        remotePartyMock = new Mock<IRemoteParty>();
        target = new Client(remotePartyMock.Object);
    }
}

#region Client & IRemoteParty

public class Client
{
    private readonly IRemoteParty remoteParty;

    /// <summary>
    /// There is a constructor injection.
    /// </summary>
    public Client(IRemoteParty remoteParty)
    {
        this.remoteParty = remoteParty;
    }

    public void DoSmth()
    {
        var tocken = remoteParty.RequestTtoken();
        remoteParty.TriggerRemoteJob(tocken);
    }
}

public interface IRemoteParty
{
    Guid RequestTtoken();

    void TriggerRemoteJob(Guid token);
}

#endregion
```